# Making both parts of expect resolve promises

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, promise, protractor

**The Problem:**

In Protractor, `expect()` is patched to implicitly understand promises which enables a *shorthand assertion style*. E.g.:

```
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual("expected text");
```

`elm.getText()` here does not need to be explicitly resolved with `then()` and would be implicitly resolved by Protractor before the expectation is checked.

But, what if the "to equal" part is also a promise. For instance, a text from an another element. In this case we have to resolve the second part explicitly:

```
elm2.getText().then(function (text2) {
    expect(elm1.getText()).toEqual(text2);
});
```

**The Question:**

Is it possible to patch Jasmine/Protractor to make it understand promises on both sides of the assertion? To be able to write:

```
expect(elm1.getText()).toEqual(elm2.getText());
```

Comment: The patch already supports  promises on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with promises for both sides - and it resolves them OK.
Try at your project. Maybe you have nothing to do:

```
describe('ololo', function () {

it('both sides are promises', function () {
    browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/testapp/ng1/#/form');

    let elementText1 = $('.ng-scope p').getText();

    let elementText2 = $('#transformedtext>h4').getText();

    //Will fail here, but you can see that it successfully resolved promises
    expect(elementText1).toEqual(elementText2);
});

});
```

If this does not work for you - i think you can use protractor.promise.all, just example:

```
protractor.promise.all([elm2.getText(), elm1.getText()])
        .then(texts=> expect(texts[0]).toEqual(texts[1]), 'texts should be same')
```

Or harder way - create own matchers. See how i work with promises inside matcher in my lib:
https://github.com/Xotabu4/jasmine-protractor-matchers/blob/master/index.js#L39

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but you could resolve the param.  It's a no-op for non promises...

```
expect(elm1.getText()).toEqual(Promise.resolve(elm2.getText()));
```