# Testing promises in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am new to the angular/protractor world so this is a really basic question. According to this [spec](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText), we can write protractor test for a web element like below:

```
var foo = element(by.id('foo'));
expect(foo.getText()).toEqual('Inner text');
```

However, foo.getText() returns a promise type, not a string, how can 'expect' compare that returned promise object against another string? Is there any documentation that explains this usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `expect()`, if used with `Protractor`, understands promises - *it would resolve a promise before making an expectation* making writing Protractor tests easier. This is actually done in a separate project which `Protractor` depends on - [`jasminewd2`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/tree/jasminewd2) which [*patches* jasmine's `expect()` to resolve the promises](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/jasminewd2/index.js#L200) and [wraps jasmine's `describe()`, `it()` and other test control block functions](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/jasminewd2/index.js#L169-L174) to be executed inside the *Control Flow*.

Note that, it also supports promises on [both sides of the assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38512113/771848), you can do, for instance:

```
let elementText1 = $('.ng-scope p').getText();
let elementText2 = $('#transformedtext>h4').getText();

expect(elementText1).toEqual(elementText2);
```

---

As far as `Protractor` documentation goes, this is partially described [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#protractor-adaptations).

Comment: Yes, it does just work out the box like that. Good answer, upvoted